# Sql Query filtering not giving me proper results

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, duplicates

[image]

I have the above table and I am trying to run a query wherein I want to show all records where MSTRNMBR (second field) has more than one unique customer.

So in the above snapshot, only MstrNmbr = '97869' has two different custNmbr.

I am trying with the below query but I am doing something wrong. Can anyone please suggest how to get above result I am looking for.

```
    SELECT MSTRNUMB,SUM(1),CUSTNMBR
    FROM SOP30200
    WHERE 2 >= 2 group by MSTRNUMB,CUSTNMBR
```

Basically I don't want to group on custnmbr but only on MSTRNMBR field.

Sorry if it is a basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query to get all MSTRNUMB with more than two distinct CUSTNMBR and also get a comma separated list of all the CUSTNMBR

```
Select MSTRNUMB, 
      STUFF(
          (SELECT ',' + CUSTNMBR FROM SOP30200
             FOR XML PATH('')),
          1, 1, '') AS Output

from SOP30200
group by MSTRNUMB
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTNMBR) > 1
```

If you want to see all CUSTNMBR associated with such MSTRNUMB then you can use below sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOP30200
WHERE MSTRNUMB IN (
    SELECT MSTRNUMB
    FROM SOP30200
    group by MSTRNUMB
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTNMBR) > 1
)
```

Comment: I can't see the second column which I guess was the custnmbr from your query. what change should I make to show only custnmbr. Currently query gets executed and second column in query output (which is custnmbr) is like so long and I can't even expand it. The sop30200 table has upto 1 million records.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve all CUSTNMBR that are associated with such MSTRNUMB ?  If so pls see the updated query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
    SELECT MstrNumbr, count(MstrNumbr) as DistinctCustomerCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT MstrNumbr, CustNmbr
        FROM SOP30200
    ) a
    GROUP BY MstrNumb
```

*EDIT:*  Updated.  The above query will just give you the MstrNumbers which are associated with more than one CustNmbr, the one below will also give you a list of those distinct customers (sorry about the trailing comma)

```
    SELECT MstrNumbr
        ,(SELECT DISTINCT CustNmbr + ','
        FROM SOP30200 s1
        WHERE s1.MstrNumbr = s2.MstrNumbr
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Customers
    FROM SOP30200 s2
    GROUP BY MstrNumbr
    HAVING COUNT(MstrNumbr) > 1
```

Comment: I ran your query and it shows 97870 and 97871 from my table data snapshot in original question. so only 97869 should be shown. I guess the query is showing as custnmbr is > 1 but it should show only when the same mstrnmbr has more than one customer. Please let me know.